# Make WP_Query more efficient?

Tags: wp-query, memory

Ok - so using a WP_Query to count votes by a user. But now there are 23,000 votes and its using up lots of memory.

Is there a way i can make this WP_Query more efficient?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'vote',
    'author'=>$user,
    'meta_key'=>'comp_question',
    'meta_value'=>$question_id,
    'meta_compare'=>'=',
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'order'=>'desc'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

any help appreciated! dc
any help appreciated!

Comment: I would look to store the results in a [transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). Depending on how often you need to recalc the data it could be a solution?

Comment: Yes, as `WP_Query`already returns count in the `$post_count`variable, I just would cache the result and update it when a user post a new vote.

Comment: yeh that's true. Just wondering if its lighter using sql? Also the below suggestion suggests disabling the cache?

Answer (score 2):

you can try some of these extra parameters:

```
 'update_post_term_cache' => false,
 'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
 'cache_results'=>false,
 'no_found_rows' => true, 
 'posts_per_page'=>1,
 'post_status'='publish',
```

ps: you can measure the speed of your query when you are testing it with `microtime()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

**Edit:**

Here is a another way:

```
function count_votes($user_id=1, $question_id=1, $post_type='vote', $meta_key='comp_question'){
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM {$wpdb->posts} INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) WHERE ({$wpdb->posts}.post_author = %d) AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_type = %s) AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' ) AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = %s) AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value = %d)"; 

    // uncomment if you need to group it
    //$sql .= "  GROUP BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID"; 

    $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql,$user_id,$post_type,$meta_key,$question_id));

    return $count;
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
$user_id=1;
$question_id=1; 
$post_type='vote'; 
$meta_key='comp_question';

echo "votes: " . count_votes($user_id, $question_id, $post_type, $meta_key);
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is a function that returns an array of votes ids:

```
function get_votes($user_id=1, $question_id=1, $post_type='vote', $meta_key='comp_question'){
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id) WHERE ({$wpdb->posts}.post_author = %d) AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_type = %s) AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish' ) AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = %s) AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value = %d)"; 

    // uncomment if you need to group it
    //$sql .= "  GROUP BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID"; 

    $ids=array();
    $ids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($sql,$user_id,$post_type,$meta_key,$question_id));

    return $ids;
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
$ids=get_votes($user_id, $question_id, $post_type, $meta_key);
print_r($ids);
```

Comment: cheers - though these seem to break the query... these work 'cache_results'=>false, 'posts_per_page'=>1, and looking to see if they reduce load.

Comment: how are you counting the votes? is your query returning 23k posts that you are counting with php? If so I would use custom sql with count(*) instead to get it.

Comment: i'm not returning 23k votes but that's how many it has to search through. I'm only looking for 1 which tells me there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: I updated the answer above with custom sql.

Comment: ps: changed it into a custom function that returns the count.

Comment: thanks - using that in some places and waiting to check for improvements. I need to return the id of the vote in once place - users can only vote once so no need to count. I think the main reason this is slowing the site down is its called per question (10) and in 3 places on the page to assign completed classes to objects. So this is getting called 30 times on one page and there are ten page! Not the best but its too late to completely redo it so need to do what i can for now. Its used by schools and they do it together - 30 kids at a time so its bottlenecking.

Comment: I added another function that returns the array of vote id's. You should consider caching the output if you can. You could also consider storing the total votes per question (updated like total=total+1)

Comment: ps: you should also consider dropping the post-revisions (if you don't need them), they can bloat your db.